# how to use gridview in scrollview so that after grid view other layout also shows up?

Tags: android

I have to make a layout in following manner:

grid with all content showing and a footer but when I enclosed grid view in scroll view so that after grid view end the footer scrolls up, grid view height cuts into one row only. how to overcome that….

I searched online there is something called expandableheightgridview but it is totally out of my reach……

so, can you explain that or any other solution in detail.